# Why is TypeScript returing Object as a type of an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

i just started learning TypeScript and started writing few snippets trying to get used to it.

Code:

```
function Print(value:any){
   console.log(`value type is : ${typeof value}`)
}

Print(10);
Print('foo');
Print(true);
**Print(["a","b"]);**
Print({'name':"foo"})
```

Output

```
value type is : number
value type is : string
value type is : boolean
**value type is : object**
value type is : object
```

why is Print(["a","b"]) returing object type when i have passed an array as its parameter.

is this an javascipt thing or just typescript?

Comment: It is a javascript thing.  The [`typeof` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) returns `"object"` for non-function objects such as arrays (arrays are indeed objects in JS).